# Most elegant way to store duplicate String elements with increasing counter at the end of every duplicated element

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, coding-efficiency

I want to transform duplicates `String[]` to `List<String>` where every next duplicated element will have increasing counter after it name.

Example:

```
Test, TestA, TestB, Test, TestA, TestA, TestB
```

should be transformed to:

```
Test, TestA, TestB, Test1, TestA1, TestA2, TestB1
```

Result must have the same order like input data, only counter is added.

Currently I wrote something like this but I don't think if it elegant and efficient way to make this and I'm looking for more proper way:

```java
String[] header = new String[]{"Test", "TestA", "TestB", "Test", "TestA", "TestA", "TestB"};
List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>();
for (String column : header) {
    if (!newHeader.contains(column)) {
        newHeader.add(column);
    } else {
        int counter = 1;
        String columnIterName = column + counter;
        while (newHeader.contains(columnIterName)) {
            columnIterName = column + counter;
            counter++;
        }
        newHeader.add(columnIterName);
    }
}
return newHeader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 8, `Map` has methods which allow to compute values if a key is missing, for example, [`Map::compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) allows to increment the counter using a `BiFunction`:

*Update*: to handle specific test: `"Test", "Test", "Test1"` when a duplicate is created as a result of appending the counter, another method `putIfAbsent` should be used.

```java
static List<String> convert(String ... header) {
    Map<String, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String column : header) {
        int count = counters.compute(column, (k, v) -> v == null ? 0 : v + 1);
        String toAdd = column + (count == 0 ? "" : Integer.toString(count));
        counters.putIfAbsent(toAdd, 0);
        result.add(toAdd);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Similar solution using Stream API may look as follows.

*Update*: here `putIfAbsent` is invoked in "cheat mode" (using `peek`)

```java
static List<String> convertStream(String ... header) {
    Map<String, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
    
    return Arrays.stream(header)
        .map(column -> column + 
            (counters.compute(column, (k, v) -> v == null ? 0 : v + 1) > 0 
            ? Integer.toString(counters.get(column)) : "")
        )
        .peek(column -> counters.putIfAbsent(column, 0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Tests:

```
String[][] tests = {
    {"Test", "Test", "Test1"},
    {"Test", "Test1", "TestA", "TestB", "Test", "Test1", "TestA", "TestA", "TestB"}
};
        
for (String[] test : tests) {
    System.out.println("convert: " + convert(test));
    System.out.println("stream : " + convertStream(test));

    System.out.println("dreamcr: " + some_method(test));
    System.out.println("------------\n");
}
```

Output:

```
convert: [Test, Test1, Test11]
stream : [Test, Test1, Test11]
dreamcr: [Test, Test1, Test11]
------------

convert: [Test, Test1, TestA, TestB, Test1, Test11, TestA1, TestA2, TestB1]
stream : [Test, Test1, TestA, TestB, Test1, Test11, TestA1, TestA2, TestB1]
dreamcr: [Test, Test1, TestA, TestB, Test1, Test11, TestA1, TestA2, TestB1]
------------
```

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that you only care about the duplicates in the original list then:**

If you use a Map to keep track of the duplicates you can simplified your code to:

```
   public static List<String> some_method(){
        String[] header = new String[]{"Test", "TestA", "TestB", "Test", "TestA", "TestA", "TestB"};
        Map<String, Integer> track = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : header){
            Integer count = track.get(s);
            if(count != null){
                count++;
                track.put(s, count);
                newHeader.add(s + count);
            }
            else{
                track.put(s, 0);
                newHeader.add(s);
            }
        }
        return newHeader;
    }
```

With this you also avoid the inner while loop.

**If you also care about the duplicates on the list being build, for instance for the input:**

```
Test Test Test1
```

you expect the output:

```
Test Test1 Test11
```

then you can use the following:

```
public static List<String> some_method(){
    String[] header = new String[]{"Test","Test","Test1"};
    Map<String, Integer> track = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : header){
        Integer count = track.get(s);
        if(count != null){
            count++;
            track.put(s, count);
            newHeader.add(s + count);
            track.put(s + count, 0);
        }
        else{
            track.put(s, 0);
            newHeader.add(s);
        }
    }
    return newHeader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` does not seem to be the best choice to match the strings, as the searches (`.contains`) are not efficient. An trying all suffixes in turn is a big waste. A `Dictionary` would be better I guess.

Then the logics is

- scan the list

  - if the string is not in the dictionary, enter it with count 1
  - else increment its count and append it to the string (in-place in the original list).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplified to the following :

```
public class Counter {
    
    public static List<String> someMethod(String[] header){
        Map<String, Integer> track = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : header){
            int count = track.compute(s, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 0 : v + 1);
            if(count != 0)
                track.put(s + count, 0);
            newHeader.add(count == 0 ? s : s + count);
        }
        return newHeader;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someMethod(new String[]{"Test","Test","Test1"}).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```